# How to make an MCD, MLD and a class diagram with Firebase Firestore?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

For my defense project I made a web application with Firebase and in my report must include a conceptual data model and a logical data model, how to achieve this with a document-oriented NoSql database such as Google Firestore ??

Comment: What are the requirments?

Comment: I have to make a logical model of the data as we would with a PHP / MySql stack with the principle of entity relations

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.